# Data from NF Tables to IP Tables

Tags: iptables, firewall, tcp, nftables, flags

I have input data like below for NF Tables:

```
nft add rule filter input tcp flags != syn 
nft add rule filter input tcp flags &syn!= syn 
add rule filter output tcp flags & (syn | ack) == syn | ack
```

Now for IPTables, I want same input data and form the rule.

How to form IP Tables rules with above tcp-flags data? Because IP tables takes tcp-flag in different template.